# C# Logon Script: RDP Remote Application get Application Name

Tags: c#, rdp, terminal-services, terminal-server

beloved community,

I'm currently writing a Logon Script for a Windows Server 2016, that gets executed whenever a user logs onto this server.

The server hosts different application which get served remotely to the user. 
So the user sets up a remote app connection under Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\RemoteApp and Desktop Connections and then he can access the applications.

The script that i wrote is writing different information to a DB, like the time the user logs on, his ip and much more. The field I'm unsure how to get is the name of the Application the user opens.

If anyone could help me out i would really appreciate it. 
Thank you in advance :]

Comment: Is your script written in C# or why is the question tagged C#? How is the script started? How does the user start the applications? From the start menu?

Comment: @mortb Thanks for your reply! Yes it is a c# console application. The script is started with the group policy, Run application at logon. 
Correct the user starts the application from the start menu.